# What is the pythonic way of saving data between function calls?

Tags: python, variables, state

The context for me is a single int's worth of info I need to retain between calls to a function which modifies that value. I could use a global, but I know that's discouraged. For now I've used a default argument in the form of a list containing the int and taken advantage of mutability so that changes to the value are retained between calls, like so--

```
 def increment(val, saved=[0]):
    saved[0] += val
    # do stuff
```

This function is being attached to a button via tkinter, like so~

```
button0 = Button(root, text="demo", command=lambda: increment(val))
```

which means there's no return value I can assign to a local variable outside the function.

How do people normally handle this? I mean, sure, the mutability trick works and all, but what if I needed to access and modify that value from multiple functions?

Can this not be done without setting up a class with static methods and internal attributes, etc?

Comment: I'd make a callable object (i.e. object with `__cal__` method so it's indistinguishable from a function). Actually, `increment` is already something with attributes, so you can assign `increment.saved = 0` after defining the function and then access `increment.saved` inside the function. I wouldn't call this Pythonic though, I'd prefer object.

Comment: why do you feel you need to save it to a _local_ variable? The scope will have long gone away by the time the button is clicked. The click happens in a private context (eg: inside `mainloop`). You can save it to a global, but to save it to a local variable makes no sense.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a class.  Use an instance member for keeping the state.

```
class Incrementable:
    def __init__(self, initial_value = 0):
        self.x = initial_value
    def increment(self, val):
        self.x += val
        # do stuff
```

You can add a `__call__` method for simulating a function call (e.g. if you need to be backward-compatible).  Whether or not it is a good idea really depends on the context and on your specific use case.

> Can this not be done without setting up a class with static methods and internal attributes, etc?

It can, but solutions not involving classes/objects with attributes are not "pythonic".  It is so easy to define classes in python (the example above is only 5 simple lines), and it gives you maximal control and flexibility.

Using python's [mutable-default-args "weirdness"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1132941/2096752) (I'm not going to call it "a feature") should be considered *a hack*.

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you mixing up model and view?

The UI elements, such as buttons, should just delegate to your data model. As such, if you have a model with a persistent state (i.e. class with attributes), you can just implement a class method there that handles the required things if a button is clicked.

**If you try to bind stateful things to your presentation (UI), you will consequently lose the desirable separation between said presentation and your data model.**

In case you want to keep your data model access simple, you can think about a `singleton` instance, such that you don't need to carry a reference to that model as an argument to all UI elements (plus you don't need a global instance, even though this `singleton` holds some kind of globally available instance):

```
def singleton(cls):
    instance = cls()
    instance.__call__ = lambda: instance
    return instance

@singleton
class TheDataModel(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0

    def on_button_demo(self):
        self.x += 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # If an element needs a reference to the model, just get
    # the current instance from the decorated singleton:
    model = TheDataModel
    print('model', model.x)
    model.on_button_demo()
    print('model', model.x)

    # In fact, it is a global instance that is available via
    # the class name; even across imports in the same session
    other = TheDataModel
    print('other', other.x)

    # Consequently, you can easily bind the model's methods
    # to the action of any UI element
    button0 = Button(root, text="demo", command=TheDataModel.on_button_demo)
```

**But, and I have to point this out,** be cautious when using `singleton` instances, as they easily lead to bad design. Set up a proper model and just make the access to the major model compound accessible as a `singleton`. Such unified access is often referred to as *context*.

Comment: This doesn't do what you think it does: `button0 = Button(root, text="demo", command=TheDataModel.on_button_demo())` You are immediately calling `on_button_demo` and assigning the result to `command`.

Comment: Well, I'm actually not used to UI elements in python, but sure - it is a call that is immediately evaluated. Don't know whether the UI elements can handle function references, but I'll fix that in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to set up a class, your only<sup>1</sup> other option is a global variable. You can't save it to a local variable because the command runs from within `mainloop`, not within the local scope in which it was created.

For example:

```
button0 = Button(root, text="demo", command=lambda: increment_and_save(val))

def increment_and_save(val):
    global saved
    saved = increment(val)
```

<sup>1</sup> not literally true, since you can use all sorts of other ways to persist data, such as a database or a file, but I assume you want an in-memory solution.

Answer (score 0):

We can make it context oriented by using `context managers`. Example is not specific to UI element however states general scenario.

```
class MyContext(object):
    # This is my container 
    # have whatever state to it
    # support different operations

    def __init__(self):
        self.val = 0

    def increament(self, val):
        self.val += val

    def get(self):
        return self.val

    def __enter__(self):
        # do on creation
        return self


    def __exit__(self, type, value, traceback):
        # do on exit
        self.val = 0

def some_func(val, context=None):
    if context:
        context.increament(val)

def some_more(val, context=None):
    if context:
        context.increament(val)

def some_getter(context=None):
    if context:
        print context.get()

with MyContext() as context:
    some_func(5, context=context)
    some_more(10, context=context)
    some_getter(context=context)
```